# Sukkot--Object or place name?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, geography, sukkah, parashas-emor

Does anyone translate "סֻכּוֹת" in [Vayikra 23:43](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0323.htm#43) as a place name rather than an object (see [Shmot 12:37](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0212.htm#37) and [13:20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0213.htm#20), where it's a place name)?
Might the Toarah mean "celebrate Sukkot because that's the first place you 'landed' as free people", to which R' Eliezer says 'protected by anannei kavod' and to which R' Akiva says --take it literally.

Comment: Interesting. But how would that fit with 23:42?

Comment: Hello Barry, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Interesting question, +1. You might consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Hope to see you around!

Comment: @DoubleAA 42 refers to booths; 43 refers to the place. לא קשיא

Comment: @Scimonster It may or not be a Kasha, but it's profoundly odd. "Sit in booths because I had your ancestors dwell in a place with a coincidentally similar sounding name."

Comment: @barrygoodlife welcome and nice question!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe any Peshat commentators offer this as an option ([I'm sure you can find it somewhere in a Chassidish Sefer](https://www.google.ca/search?safe=active&client=opera&hs=TFT&ei=9PlMWu6dE4qvjwT30L2QDg&q=%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99%20%22%D7%95%D7%99%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%22&oq=%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99%20%22%D7%95%D7%99%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11701.14735.0.15071.3.3.0.0.0.0.246.513.0j2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.qJWJrClcFY4)), for a number of reasons:

1. The Nikkud of **Ba**sukkos seems to imply in "The" Sukkos, meaning the Sukkos that we were in.  If it was referring to the place, it would say "**Be**Sukkos".
2. As mentioned above by DoubleAA, this does not seem to fit with the previous Passuk, as it would make the flow of the Pesukim very odd.
3. (I would not normally bring a proof from Chazal, but being as you understood it to be according to them in your question...) It is impossible to understand Rabbi Akiva as referring to the place "Sukkos", as he says "they **made/built** literal Sukkos", not just "literal Sukkos":

> ענני כבוד היו דברי רבי אליעזר, רבי עקיבא אומר: סוכות ממש **עשו להם**

I always value original thinking, which this certainly was, especially considering some of the other Peshat factors, like the word "Hoshavti", so kudos to you on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your question for the reason to celebrate Sukkot in connection of the first location the Jewish Nation landed by, seems to be the actual debate of Divine Cloud versus actual huts.

The Medrashim make this frankley clear. This one is Michelta of Rabbi Yishmael

כְּהֶרֶף עַיִן נָסְעוּ בְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל מֵרַעְמְסֵס לְסֻכּוֹת, לְקַיֵּם מַה שֶּׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״אַתֶּם רְאִיתֶם אֲשֶׁר עָשִׂיתִי לְמִצְרָיִם, וָאֶשָּׂא אֶתְכֶם עַל כַּנְפֵי נְשָׁרִים, וָאָבִא אֶתְכֶם אֵלָי״ (שמות י״ט:ד׳). ״סֻכֹּתָה״, סֻכּוֹת מַמָּשׁ הָיוּ, דִכְתִיב: ״וְיַעֲקֹב נָסַע סֻכֹּתָה״ (בראשית ל״ג:י״ז). דִּבְרֵי רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר. וַחֲכָמִים אוֹמְרִים: אֵין ״סֻכּוֹת״ אֶלָּא מָקוֹם, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״וַיִּסְעוּ מִסֻּכֹּת וַיַּחֲנוּ בְאֵתָם״ (במדבר ל״ג:ו׳). מָה ׳אֵתָם׳ מָקוֹם, אַף ׳סֻכּוֹת׳ מָקוֹם. רַבִּי עֲקִיבָה אוֹמֵר: אֵין סֻכּוֹת אֶלָּא עֲנָנֵי כָבוֹד, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״וּבָרָא י״י עַל כָּל מְכוֹן הַר צִיּוֹן וְעַל מִקְרָאֶהָ עָנָן יוֹמָם וְעָשָׁן וְנֹגַהּ אֵשׁ לֶהָבָה לָיְלָה, כִּי עַל כָּל כָּבוֹד חֻפָּה״ (ישעיהו ד׳:ה׳). אֵין לִי אֶלָּא לְשֶׁעָבַר, לֶעָתִיד לָבֹא מְנַיִן? תִּלְמֹד לוֹמַר: ״וְסֻכָּה תִּהְיֶה לְצֵל יוֹמָם מֵחֹרֶב, וּלְמַחְסֶה וּלְמִסְתּוֹר מִזֶּרֶם וּמִמָּטָר״ (ישעיהו ד׳:ו׳). וְאוֹמֵר: ״וּפְדוּיֵי י״י יְשֻׁבוּן, וּבָאוּ צִיּוֹן בְּרִנָּה, וְשִׂמְחַת עוֹלָם עַל רֹאשָׁם״ (ישעיהו לָהּ,י). רַבִּי נְחֶמְיָה אוֹמֵר: ״סֻכֹּתָה״, לְפִי שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לָמֵ״ד מִתְּחִלָּתוֹ, נוֹתֵן לוֹ הֵ״א בְסוֹפוֹ.

In an instant, Israel traveled from Ramses to Succoth, as per (Ibid. 19:4) "And I bore you on eagles' wings, etc." "to succoth": "succoth," ("booths") literally, as in (Genesis 33:17) "And Jacob traveled to Succoth, and for his cattle he made succoth (booths), for which reason the place was named Succoth." These are the words of R. Eliezer. R. Akiva says: "succoth" refers to the clouds of glory, as in (Isaiah 4:5) "And the Lord will create on the entire base of Mount Zion and on all of its branchings a cloud by day and smoke with a glow of flaming fire by night, on all the glory, a canopy." This tells me only of the past. Whence do I derive (the same for) the time to come? From (Ibid. 6) "And it shall be a succah to shade the day", (Ibid. 35:10) "And the redeemed of the Lord will return, etc." And the sages say: Succoth is a place, as in (Exodus 13:20) "And they journeyed from Succoth and they encamped in Etham." Just as Etham is a place, so, Succoth. R. Nechemiah says: "Succothah": The (conventional) "lamed" ("to") in the beginning is replaced by a "heh" at the end.

This one is Michilta of Rabbi Shimon ben Yochia:
(לז)  וַיִּסְע֧וּ בְנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֛ל מֵרַעְמְסֵ֖ס סֻכֹּ֑תָה כְּשֵׁשׁ־מֵא֨וֹת אֶ֧לֶף רַגְלִ֛י הַגְּבָרִ֖ים לְבַ֥ד מִטָּֽף׃

**סכתה** – ר׳ עקיבה אומר סכות ממש עשו להן בסכות: ר׳ אליעזר אומר סכות ענני כבוד כאו וחנו על גבי רעמסס.

It appears that the name סוכתה was established based on the event of the Jewish departure from Egypt according to the famous debate of the reason for this holiday.